# Java で内部クラスのメソッドをオーバーライドしたい

Tags: java

Java で以下のようなことは可能でしょうか。

```
abstract class A<T extends B> {
  T baz;

  A() {}

  String getFoo() {
    return this.baz.b1;
  }

  class B {
    String b1;
    B() {
      this.b1 = "bar";
    }
  }
}

class A' extends A<B'> {
  A'() {
    this.baz = new B'();
  }

  String getBar() {
    return this.baz.b2;
  }

  class B' extends B {
    String b2;
    B'() {
      super();
      this.b2 = "bar";
    }
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A' a = new A'();
    System.out.println(a.getFoo() + a.getBar()); // out "foobar"
  }
}
```

また、クラス B のメソッドをクラス B' でオーバーライドすることは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 6):

可能ですが、サンプルコードは、`A`クラスの宣言部で既にエラーが起こっていますよ。

Aの宣言時に内部クラスが見つからないのでエラーになります。（Aクラスの定義行自体は`A`クラスの内部にない＝Bクラスがスコープ外)

```
class A<T extends B> { // B にアクセスできない
    class B {}
}
```

以下だと大丈夫。

```
class A<T extends A.B> {
    class B {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

コードの意図はあまり読めていませんが、コンパイルは以下で通ります

Javaのクラスの使用
http://www.ne.jp/asahi/hishidama/home/tech/java/class_use.html

```
abstract class A<T extends A.B> {
  T baz;

  A() {}

  String getFoo() {
    return this.baz.b1;
  }

  class B {
    String b1;
    B() {
      this.b1 = "bar";
    }
  }
}

class Adash extends A<Adash.Bdash> {

  Adash() {
    this.baz = new Bdash();
  }

  String getBar() {
    return this.baz.b2;
  }

  class Bdash extends A.B {
    String b2;
    Bdash() {
      super();
      this.b2 = "bar";
    }
  }
}

/**
 * ここから実行
 */
public class prog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Adash a = new Adash();
        System.out.println(a.getFoo() + a.getBar()); // out "foobar"
    }
}
```

[wandboxでのライブデモ](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sPhriQmqAJTqN5oR)